# How to access HelloWorld app which I just created in Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I just created my first HelloWorld app for Windows Phone 8. This app has just one button and when you click on it, displays message "Hello World".

I pressed F5 and the emulator ran and now I can see Windows Phone 8 running inside emulator but where's my app? I can't seem to find it anywhere?

Comment: Have you tried swiping over to the all apps list and looking in that list for your app?

Comment: If you have pressed F5, then you do not need to do anything. The app should run by itself. If it doesn't, from the homescreen of the emulator, swipe left, and then swipe up until you see your app, "HelloWorld", in the app list. From there you can launch your app.

Comment: I have already done this. When emulator runs, it shows home screen so I swiped to left and was expecting my app in H category (because my solution name is HelloWorld) but it wasn't there. In fact it was nowhere on that page.

Comment: try deploying it in a device and see if you do have?

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: No error. It successfully runs emulator when I press F5.